# Inner container floating out top of parent on IE11

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="bottombar"> 
    <div class="outercontainer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="devider">
                <p class="toptitle">dis-rupt-ifi</p>
                <p class="pheader-sub">disrpt/<br /><em>verb</em></p>
            </div>
            <div class="pheader">   
                We solve problems using design and technology.<br> we help and businesses consume data.<br> We use data design to drive your bottom line.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.bottombar{
    background-color: #475A54;
    padding: 0px 0 100px 0;
}

.outercontainer {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.devider{
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
    padding-right: 90px;
}

.pheader{
    text-transform: none !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    letter-spacing: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 400px;
    line-height: 1.8;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
    .container {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .devider{
        float:none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .pheader{
        padding-left: 0;
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px){
    .pheader{
        padding-left: 0;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

This is it rendered in Chrome:

[image]

And this is it in IE11:

[image]

And I can't for the life of me get this to work correctly in IE. Any tips or pointers? Thanks :)

PS - I know this is not the best way to have done this layout, this is just a quick problem I need to solve on a clients site. So spit and duckt-tape!

Comment: add code like jsfiddle

Comment: provide fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the lack of support for `display: flex` in IE11. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: At first I also thought so, though changing display: flex, to display: inline-block still works fine on Chrome, but IE persists to have the same issue.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on parent element?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because in your screenshot, you rendered using IE browser with browser's width < 980px, while in Chrome your browser's width is > 980px.
Try to resize your browser's width so they are the same.
i.e. you may get the same result too if you narrowing your Chrome browser, because there are responsive css kicking out if browser's width less than 980px and another one when less than 736px.

Comment: If chrome is the same width as IE the result is still the same. :(

Comment: you mean the chrome rendering stil have the "We solve..." text on the right side? Trying with chrome width < 980 should have the "We solve..." text below the "dis-rupt..." text, according to your css.